# How do I run a batch of processes concurrently, and start new ones when one completes?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, sh

Basically, You can think of this as a bag of tasks, where we have, say, 1000 tasks and something like 64 cores. I want to run one task per core, and when one task completes, I want to start a new one.

How do I do this in Bash? I think C++, I could do this pretty easily, but it's not clear to me how to do this in bash. I have spent a fair amount of time on Google, and I understand I need to use & to background a process, but while necessary, it's still insufficient.

Any tips, code snippets, etc would help.

Comment: search here for `xargs` and `gnu-parallel`. This problem is already solved ;-). But StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems.  Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [unix.se]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions. AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: From what I've seen, Gnu Parallel won't start a new task when one finishes. For example, I want to run 100 tasks on 50 cores, it won't start a new one once one finishes. Perhaps I have missed something, though?

Comment: assuming there's a reason `xargs` and `parallel` can't be used, use a `while` loop and counter to spawn, say, 50 jobs in parallel; once the counter hits 50 (while still inside the loop) run `wait -n` - this will wait until (at least) one process completes - at which point you can continue your loop and start a new job; if your version of `bash` does not support `wait -n` you can roll your own polling process (ie, run `jobs` and count the number of background jobs; if the count < 50 then spawn a new job) ...

Comment: ... ; in place of `wait -n` you would then use `sleep X` - where X is some reasonable amount of time to sleep (, eg, 10 seconds if most jobs are expected to take a few minutes?) - and then run the `jobs|wc` again to see if any jobs completed during the last X seconds

Comment: Your question is about Linux, but it is not an entirely programming question. Such questions are off-topic here, but they are on-topic on the https://unix.stackexchange.com . Please visit that site and re-ask there.